# Find out name of the 3G interface on Android

Tags: android, terminal, 3g, busybox, ifconfig

I am trying to find out the name of the 3G interface inside my Android cell phone.

I have `BusyBox` installed.

I've been told I should see it when I run in the terminal:

```
busybox ifconfig
```

What I get is:

```
$ busybox ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:21778 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21778 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:10128017 (9.6 MiB)  TX bytes:10128017 (9.6 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:A7:CF:44:5A:F2
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::46a7:cfff:fe44:5af2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1370 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1963531 (1.8 MiB)  TX bytes:199846 (195.1 KiB)
```

How do get from this the name of the 3G interface?
Or if this is not the right way to do it, then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly disable your wifi, be sure that cellular data are enable, then repeat the command. 
You may see something like rmnet0.

Comment: you can also run this command in a terminal "ls /sys/class/net". The list of directories is also the list of interfaces used or configured.